# Stuck in Link's Awakening on G&W, can I recover and continue on or will I have to restart this save?

Tags: zelda-links-awakening

I just got the Zelda Game & Watch and playing through Link's Awakening. Apparently this version of the game is the original GB version with the screen warping glitch intact that I'm abusing the heck out of in this playthough.

I inadvertently walked off a screen when glitching around and I ended up in Eagle Tower early. I decided to just work my way out back to the entrance of the level to leave so I could get whatever goodies can be found in that part of the map. Well I'm stuck in the tower since the entrance is locked. And I saved trying to get out of there. This made matters worse and I'm actually stuck on the door and can't move or go back into the tower.

[image: stuck]

Am I actually stuck here and have to restart again? Or are there any (in game) techniques that I could exploit to get me out of this mess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I think I'm screwed and have to start over. According to the [Zelda Wiki](https://zelda.fandom.com/wiki/Glitches_in_Link%27s_Awakening#Screen_Warp_Glitch) on the glitch, I did everything I was not supposed to do (emphasis mine):

> Dangers: Screen-warping is generally safe, but there are several dangerous situations to avoid. Don't attempt to warp through the Nightmare doors. The game crashes spectacularly and fades to white while having the text box stating that the door is locked. Upon rebooting the system, your save files are usually all gone! **If you end up inside the cave where the Magnifying Glass is located or in Eagle's Tower, don't exit out to the overworld unless you have already freed the entrance. If you DO exit, and become stuck inside the statue or the wall, do NOT save and exit in an attempt to free yourself. If you do, that file will be stuck in that spot forever.**

I *was* in Eagle's Tower, I *did* exit to the overworld before opening the entrance, I *did* get stuck, I *did* save and exit, I *am* stuck in that spot forever. Oh well.

Comment: Yep, saving before closing the game was definitely not a good idea...